# Ensuring all Api's has been loaded in a page in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have 4 controllers in a page in AngularJS. Each controller calls Api's via http request(scope $http). I want to ensure that all the Api's has been called and loaded till then I can show the loading gif image. How to check all the Api's has been loaded in the page in AngulaJS.

Comment: say `$http request 2` gets failed somehow ,you want to load the rest .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I am not sharing the exact code some variable and name I have modified.    
 myApp.controller('testController',function ($scope, $http, $q, $filter) {

    var _promises = {};

        _promises['abc'] =
            $http({
                url: API_URL+'abc-type/',
                method: 'GET',
                params: {'test1': 'test2'}
            });

        _promises['abc1'] =
            $http({
                url: API_URL+'abc-type2/',
                method: 'GET'
            });

        }
    $q.all(_promises).then(function (res) {
            alert("All promises executed.");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) uses promises (`$q`) for it's API. You can use the [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) method to run a callback when an array of `$http` requests are resolved (you will need to make sure all service requests return promises to avoid undefined behavior).

> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.

It would look something like this

```
$scope.showLoadingGif = true;
$q.all([MyService.makeGet(), MyService.makeAnotherGet(), ...]).then(function(responses) {
    // all the calls have returned a response by this point
    $scope.showLoadingGif = false;
})
```

Comment: `all(function(responses)` it should be `then(function(responses)` .

Comment: I have used the $q promise to check for the api loading in the controller and that solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for this my problem got resolved again I got stuck in a similar situation.